# Simple- How To select an Item from a WPF combo box using coded UI

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, coded-ui-tests

I have worked with coded UI for web applications but for the first time I am trying to leverage Coded UI for WPF. I want to perform a click on an item from a combobox But, I am unable to achieve the same here in WPF. I tried to loop through the items inside the combo box but It did not work. Tried with Search Property - No result. Also, was trying to figure out the AutomationElement stuff but not able to get a solution. It would be great if I can get an idea of the approach that needs to be followed to achieve the requirement.

I have captured the controls and want to play around with them. No record and playback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the WpfComboBox's SelectedItem property which takes the name of the item you want to select (as mentioned in my comment in yonder answer)

```
var myComboBox = this.UIMap.UIMainWindowWindow.UIItemComboBox;
var items = myComboBox.Items;
myComboBox.SelectedItem = items[0].Name;
```

or you can simply set the SelectedIndex if you already know the index of the item you want to set

```
var myComboBox = this.UIMap.UIMainWindowWindow.UIItemComboBox;
var items = myComboBox.Items;
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or you can first click the combobox to get it expanded and then get the UITestControl for the item element and perform a click on it (unfortunately you have to manually click the combobox because it seems that the ExpandWhileSearching configuration it doesn't work on it)

```
var myComboBox = this.UIMap.UIMainWindowWindow.UIItemComboBox;
var items = myComboBox.Items;
Mouse.Click(myComboBox);
Mouse.Click(items[0]);
```

or

```
var myComboBox = this.UIMap.UIMainWindowWindow.UIItemComboBox;
var items = myComboBox.Items;
myComboBox.Expanded = true;
Mouse.Click(items[0]);
```

Comment: If you dont mind, Could you please refer to the Last comment of the second answer!

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this, where do you enter the search string, i.e. the display value of the listbox item you want to select?

Comment: There: myComboBox.SelectedItem = name;
The setter for the SelectedItem property sets the selected item for the UI control.

Answer (score 0):

You would create the combobox object the same way you would in Html, just using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls` namespace.  For example:

```
public WpfComboBox tester
{
    get
    {
        WpfComboBox target = new WpfComboBox();
        return target;
    }
}
```

Then, you will create a `UITestControlCollection` object to store the .Items of the combo box.

```
UITestControlCollection comboBoxItems = tester.Items;
```

From here, you should be able to edit and set selected items ( `tester.SelectedItem = comboBoxItems[0].ToString();`) at will.

Comment: Are you trying to say that I should create the WpfComboBox with search and filter properties and then get the Items? Btw I tried like this:- 
     UITestControlCollection comboBoxItems = this.UIMap.MyWPFCombobox.Items 
It was throwing an exception though.

Comment: Exactly.  Unless you've already created it, of course.  I wasn't sure from your question if you were trying to do both or just the second part.

Comment: In this case I already have the combobox control recorded then why do I have to create it with search filter properties ?

Comment: As I stated before, if you've already created it, you don't have to do so again.  Just get the .Items of your **current** combo box and set the .SelectedItem to the one that you wish.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and the Item that I was getting was somewhat like this:- Name [UnitializedCB3702D1-14B6-4001-8BC7-CD4C22C18BE1], ControlType [ListItem], AutomationId [UnitializedCB3702D1-14B6-4001-8BC7-CD4C22C18BE1], RuntimeId [7,7612,55939488] and when I am trying to assign it back to selected item - An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code. kindly suggest

Comment: The problem is that SelectedItem = SomeString searches for an item with the name SomeString. The UITestControl.ToString() gets the whole object description not the name of the control.

Comment: Very Valid Point ! Is there a way we can get the value to set from this  Name [UnitializedCB3702D1-14B6-4001-8BC7-CD4C22C18BE1], ControlType [ListItem], AutomationId [UnitializedCB3702D1-14B6-4001-8BC7-CD4C22C18BE1], RuntimeId [7,7612,55939488]

Comment: SelectedItem = comboBoxItem[0].Name;